# Show/Hide JavaScript with radio buttons (hide not working)

Tags: javascript, radio-button, show-hide

I am not that experienced with JavaScript so I apologize if this seems simple. I have a form with 4 radio buttons and each option has additional corresponding fields. When the form loads, the additional fields are hidden and should only appear when the correct radio button is selected. I was able to get the fields to display correctly, however, cannot get them to hide when a different radio button is selected. I looked through other posts on similar issues but couldn't find anything that worked. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**XSL Code:**

```
<input type="radio" name=rdoRequestType" id="mvrRequest" value='MVR"
   onclick="saveRadioButton('MVR', 'abcRequestType');showOptions();">
   <xsl:if test="$RequestType = 'MVR'">
       <xsl:attribute name="checked">true</xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:if>
</input>

<input type="radio" name=rdoRequestType" id="mocRequest" value='MOC"
   onclick="saveRadioButton('MOC', 'abcRequestType');showOptions();">
   <xsl:if test="$RequestType = 'MOC'">
       <xsl:attribute name="checked">true</xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:if>
</input>

<input type="radio" name=rdoRequestType" id="mtcRequest" value='MTC"
   onclick="saveRadioButton('MTC', 'abcRequestType');showOptions();">
   <xsl:if test="$RequestType = 'MTC'">
       <xsl:attribute name="checked">true</xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:if>
</input>

<input type="radio" name=rdoRequestType" id="ltuRequest" value='LTU"
   onclick="saveRadioButton('LTU', 'abcRequestType');showOptions();">
   <xsl:if test="$RequestType = 'LTU'">
       <xsl:attribute name="checked">true</xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:if>
</input>

<div id='MVR' style="display:none">
   <p>Additional text 1</p>
</div>

<div id='MOC' style="display:none">
   <p>Additional text 2</p>
</div>

<div id='MTC' style="display:none">
   <p>Additional text 3</p>
</div>

<div id='LTU' style="display:none">
   <p>Additional text 4</p>
</div>
```

I have the below as an external JavaScript file:

```
function showOptions()
{
  if (document.getElementById('mvrRequest').checked)
  {
  document.getElementById('MVR').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('MOC').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('MTC').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('LTU').style.display = "none";    
  }
  else if (document.getElementById('mocRequest').checked)
  {
  document.getElementById('MOC').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('MVR').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('MTC').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('LTU').style.display = "none";        
  }
  else if (document.getElementById('mtcRequest').checked)
  {
  document.getElementById('MTC').style.display = 'block';   
  document.getElementById('MVR').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('MOC').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('LTU').style.display = "none";        
  }
  else if (document.getElementById('ltuRequest').checked)
  {
  document.getElementById('LTU').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('MVR').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('MOC').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('MTC').style.display = "none";        
  }

}
```

Comment: Any error messages in the console?

Comment: @Teemu, those ids belong to the divs below. Anyways I created a jsfiddle but it does not seem to show the divs either. https://jsfiddle.net/oh39zj3L/

Comment: Your XSL quoting is messy, also, `input` doesn't have end tag. With corrected fiddle options and quoting, and added `saveRadioButton` function, your code [seems to work](https://jsfiddle.net/oh39zj3L/).